# Jetty excluding some cipher suites. Why?

Tags: java, cryptography, jetty

I have recently updated environment in which my server using Jetty works and it seems that some ciphers was excluded. According to `sslContextFactory.getExcludeCipherSuites()` it is:

```
^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$
```

I have not excluded it myself. I cannot find it in any Jetty changelog, but I see that Jetty 9.3.12 has does not exclude those ciphers. Now versions 9.3.13 and 9.3.14 exclude them. Do you know how to include such ciphers back? I need them because some clients must work on very old and unsupported systems (WinXP) with very old and unsupported browsers (MS IE 7).

I use jdk1.8.0_112 from Oracle and Jetty 9.3.13/Jetty 9.3.14 on RedHat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I know that MD5 and SHA1 algorithms are not secure I must support MS IE7 users who can connect using `SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`. As sbordet answered me on [Jetty github](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1085) I had to call:

```
sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites()
```

(no params in method call means reset)

Comment: Which will work until the "Global SHA1-Deprecation" on Jan 1, 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Those ciphersuites are insecure:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Attacks

Comment: The cipher suites using `MD5/SHA/SHA1` will stop being used by released browsers on Jan 1, 2017 too.

Comment: I know, but some clients use WinXP (grrh) which can use only insecure SHA algorithms. We will get worse ratings in ssllabs.com tests, but they have to work.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory-cipherSuites

Comment: I checked and Jetty 9.3.12 does not exclude those ciphers. Newer versions 9.3.13 and brand new 9.3.14 exclude them. I exclude some weak algorithms by myself to get high scores on `ssllabs.com` tests, but some must be enabled because of very old clients (MS IE7 on WinXP).